# If both the sum and the difference of two sequences converge, do the individual sequences converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove or else give a counterexample: If $x_n + y_n$ converges and if $x_n - y_n$ converges, then $x_n$ converges and $y_n$ converges.

My work so far:

Suppose that $x_n + y_n$ converges to $L$ and $x_n - y_n$ converges to $M$.

We know that there exists an $N_1$ in the natural numbers such that $n > N_1$ implies that $|(x_n + y_n) - L| < \epsilon$.

We know that there exists an $N_2$ in the natural numbers such that $n > N_2$ implies that $|(x_n - y_n) - M| < \epsilon$.

Let $N = \max\{N_1,N_2\}$. Then, for all $n > N$, we have
\begin{align}
    && |(x_n + y_n) - L| + |(x_n - y_n) - M| && < 2 \epsilon \\
    -2 \epsilon < && x_n + y_n - L + x_n - y_n - M && < 2 \epsilon \\
    -2 \epsilon < && 2 x_n - L - M && < 2 \epsilon \\
    - \epsilon < && x_n - \frac{L - M}{2} && < \epsilon \\
    && \Big|x_n - \frac{L - M}{2}\Big| && < \epsilon
\end{align}
Therefore, $x_n$ converges to $\frac{L - M}{2}$.

My problem is trying to make this work for $y_n$ as well. I feel like it should be relatively simple to adapt this to show that $y_n$ converges, but I've been playing around with multiplying by -1 and the triangle inequality, and I can't seem to get it to come out right.

Comment: Show, generally, that $a_n \to a$ and $b_n \to b$ implies $a_n+b_n \to a+b$. Then, you get $x_n \to \frac{L+M}{2}$ (+, not -), and $y_n \to \frac{L-M}{2}$ (since $a_n-b_n = a_n+(-b_n) \to a+(-b) = a-b$).

Comment: Just interchange the letters x and y, and interchange the letters L and M, in all of it.

Comment: what's wrong with what you did is you said $\frac{-L-M}{2} = -\frac{L-M}{2}$. Be careful putting minus signs in numerators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost trivial: the sum, which is $2x_n$, also converges (to $L+M$), so $x_n\to\frac{L+M}{2}.$ For $y_n$ consider the difference.

Comment: That makes sense. I was making it too complicated. Instead I could just go $(x_n + y_n) + (x_n - y_n) \rightarrow L+ M \Rightarrow 2 x_n \rightarrow L+M \Rightarrow x_n \rightarrow \frac{L + M}{2}$, and similarly for $y_n$ using the difference. I must admit though, I remain curious about what was wrong with my original work, since apparently I got the wrong answer for what the limit is.

Answer (score 2):

Since $x_n+y_n \to l$ and $x_n-y_n \to s$

Then $2x_n=(x_n+y_n)+(x_n-y_n) \to l+s \Longrightarrow x_n \to \frac{l+s}{2}$

Similarly proove the convergence of $y_n$

Answer (score 0):

If $\{x_n + y_n\}$ and  $\{x_n - y_n\}$ converge.

Then $\{(x_n +y_n) + (x_n - y_n)\}$ and $\{(x_n + y_n) - (x_n + y_n)\}$ converge.

And so do $\{k[(x_n +y_n) + (x_n - y_n)]\}$ and $\{j[(x_n +y_n) - (x_n - y_n)]\}$ for any constants $k$ and $j$.